# Disconnected during download - Blackberry / JavaME

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to download a file from a server using blackberry's wifi. However, it kept getting disconnected. Is there anyway I can ensure or do something about it so it will not be interrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to check is to make sure you are indeed using a wifi connection. Are you adding `;interface=wifi;deviceside=true` to the url that you are passing to the `Connector.Open` method? Otherwise, Blackberry will try to open a connection via BIS/BES and those routes limit the size of the files you can download. See [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242) forum discussion for some info regarding Blackberry networking caveats.

Answer (score 2):

Network connectivity is out of your control, especially on mobile.  The best you can do is set up your application to automatically reconnect and resume downloading using the HTTP "Range" header (assuming the web server supports it).

Comment: From what i know, is it true that bb doesn't allow reconnection?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Just call Connector.open() again, and once connected make sure to set the "Range" header in the request.